# Mantle property class based on another property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, github-mantle

How can I use Github Mantle to choose a property class based on another property in the same class?  (or in the worse case another part of the JSON object).

For example if i have an object like this:

```
{
  "content": {"mention_text": "some text"},
  "created_at": 1411750819000,
  "id": 600,
  "type": "mention"
}
```

I want to make a transformer like this:

```
+(NSValueTransformer *)contentJSONTransformer {
    return [MTLValueTransformer transformerWithBlock:^id(NSDictionary* contentDict) {
          return [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:ETMentionActivityContent.class fromJSONDictionary:contentDict error:nil];
    }];
}
```

But the dictionary passed to the transformer only includes the 'content' piece of the JSON, so I don't have access to the 'type' field.   Is there anyway to access the rest of the object?  Or somehow base the model class of 'content' on the 'type'?

I have previously been forced to do hack solutions like this:

```
+(NSValueTransformer *)contentJSONTransformer {
    return [MTLValueTransformer transformerWithBlock:^id(NSDictionary* contentDict) {
        if (contentDict[@"mention_text"]) {
            return [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:ETMentionActivityContent.class fromJSONDictionary:contentDict error:nil];
        } else {
            return [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:ETActivityContent.class fromJSONDictionary:contentDict error:nil];
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can pass the type information by modifying the `JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey` method:

```
+ (NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey
{
    return @{
        NSStringFromSelector(@selector(content)) : @[ @"type", @"content" ],
    };
}
```

Then in `contentJSONTransformer`, you can access the "type" property:

```
+ (NSValueTransformer *)contentJSONTransformer 
{
    return [MTLValueTransformer ...
        ...
        NSString *type = value[@"type"];
        id content = value[@"content"];
    ];
}
```

Comment: It is perfect solution! Thanks. Many problems have solved.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue, and I suspect my solution isn't much better than yours.

I have a common base class for my Mantle objects, and after each is constructed, I call a configure method to give them chance to set up properties that are dependent on more than one "base" (== JSON) property.

Like this:

```
+(id)entityWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary {

    NSError* error = nil;
    Class derivedClass = [self classWithDictionary:dictionary];
    NSAssert(derivedClass,@"entityWithDictionary failed to make derivedClass");
    HVEntity* entity = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:derivedClass fromJSONDictionary:dictionary error:&error];
    NSAssert(entity,@"entityWithDictionary failed to make object");
    entity.raw = dictionary;
    [entity configureWithDictionary:dictionary]; // Give the new entity a chance to set up derived properties
    return entity;
}
```