# Mantle Objective C: mapping nested properties to JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, github-mantle

I want to use `Mantle` to serialize some objects to this `JSON`:

```
{
"name": "John Smith",
"age": 30,
"department_id":123
}
```

I have two classes Department Employee:

```
#import <Mantle/Mantle.h>

    @interface Department : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>

    @property(nonatomic)int id;
    @property(nonatomic)NSString *name;

    @end
```

and the Employee class:

```
#import <Mantle/Mantle.h>
#import "Department.h"

    @interface Employee : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>

    @property(nonatomic)NSString *name;
    @property(nonatomic)int age;
    @property(nonatomic)Department *department;

    @end

@implementation Employee
+ (NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey {

    return @{
             @"name":@"name",
             @"age":@"age",
             @"department.id":@"department_id"
             };
}
@end
```

> when serializing an Employee instance I receive the following
>   exception: "NSInternalInconsistencyException", "department.id is not a
>   property of Employee."

What's wrong here? is there a way to serialize the object as as a single dictionary instead of nesting the department object inside the employee object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it from here:
[Mantle property class based on another property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26122616/mantle-property-class-based-on-another-property)

I modified the mapping dictionary to be like this

```
+ (NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey {

    return @{
             @"name":@"name",
             @"age":@"age",
             NSStringFromSelector(@selector(department)) : @[@"department_id"]
             };
}
```

and added:

```
    + (NSValueTransformer *)departmentJSONTransformer {
        return [MTLValueTransformer transformerUsingReversibleBlock:^id(Department *department, BOOL *success, NSError *__autoreleasing *error) {
           return [MTLJSONAdapter JSONDictionaryFromModel:department error:nil];
        }];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

first remove this code from your  Employee.m file

```
@implementation Employee
+ (NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey {

    return @{
             @"name":@"name",
             @"age":@"age",
             @"department.id":@"department_id"
             };
}
```

and then use the following whenever you want to `serialize` the `Employee` object

```
Employee *objEmployee = [Employee instanceFromDict:responseObject];
```

I hope it will work for you. All the best!!

Comment: Thanks, but I want to serialize the employee object, I want to convert it to a JSON dictionary. not the other way (serializing/parsing)

Comment: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368867/generate-json-string-from-nsdictionary-in-ios"  ....check this link!!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm asking about implementing this using Mantle library.